# Nav-bar partly hiding <h1> heading on device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am making a bootstrap website for my iPad. When my iPad is up right my `h1` gets half cut off.

Is there something I can change or do to stop this?

Wouldn't mind the nav bar showing the `h1` and being in that collapse mode like on mobile.

[image: the problem]

```html
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>TEST SITE </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="scicon.gif"/>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.google.com/">This is google</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="index.php"><font color="">Home</font></a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?BookA"><font color="">Book In</font></a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?Measu;Update"><font color="">Measure &amp; Update</font></a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?Views"><font color="">Filter/Search</font></a>
                     </font>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?Toolbar"><font color="">Tools</font></a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?Load"><font color="">Co-Load LoadList</font></a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="index.php?S_Check"><font color="">Stock Check</font></a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.navbar -->
      <div id="top" class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
      </br>
      <div class="h1s">
         <h1>GRN System</h1>
      </div>
```

Comment: It appears to be working on the code snippet.

Comment: @ChadJTreadway Sorry missed out my google link for some reason. Please see now. It goes underneath and cuts of the h1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 ways you could do it.

1) Trigger the hamburger menu earlier 
2) Adjust the left and right padding on the menu:

```
.nav > li > a {
    padding: 10px 8px;
}
```

I have done that numerous times to "fit" all the menu items a client wants at the top level. If you do the latter you can do it globally through the variable in the LESS file.

Comment: Glad I could help! Been there when I was first starting with Bootstrap!